# Creating a package in R using RStudio

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I've created a bunch of files:

- init.r
- auth.r
- class.r
- modules/status.r
- modules/mgmt.r
- modules/core.r
- modules/mcf.r

The source of the init.r file is:

```
# initiation of package

# include libraries
library(RCurl);
library(rjson);

# include files
source('auth.r');
source('class.r');

# extend class
source('modules/status.r');
source('modules/mgmt.r');
source('modules/core.r');
source('modules/mcf.r');
```

How do I go about creating a package out of this? The init.r file obviously needs to be initiated first.

Comment: I think you will benefit by studying how to build a package by hand then figure out how to use RStudio to aid in the process. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html

Comment: Surely the benefit of RStudio is that it removes that obligation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with following the steps in this video:

[Build an R Package in under 2 minutes with RStudio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScV7XXlBZww)

Then read more about [RStudio's Package Development](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/packages/overview) feature, and also [Hadley Wickam's Package basics](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Package-basics).

Comment: [Hadley Wickam's R packaging book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) subsumes the linked package basics (and is free too).

Answer (score 6):

See `Writing R Extensions` for the process of making a package. You might want to use `package.skeleton` to get started.

But essentially,

- get rid of your `init.r` file,
- put all your other `.R` files in the `R` directory
- write `Depends: RCurl, rjson` in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Thanks, I've read most of the material, however I find it very hard to learn. I've done all of what you've said (mainly following https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Package-basics), but the thing is, the class.r file contains a setRefClass, and the subsequent files (all those previously in the modules-folder) requires this class. Should I just write require('class.r') in the top of these files? - In other words: how can I define the order of how these are loaded?

Comment: If everything else fails, you could do what all of did (and still do) and *Read The Fine Manual*.  And/or look at existing packages. CRAN has a few...

Comment: `require` is about loading a package. I don't know how your code works, but you should not need a specific order. Essentially inside the .R file should be class declarations (`setRefClass`, ...) and functions. So by the time you use your functions, the class are already created ...

Comment: class.r contains `rga <- setRefClass('rga', ...)` and the subsequent modules files contains `rga$methods(list(...))`. If the subsequent files are loaded before, it will produce an error. The auth.r file contains a class-constructor function. Maybe I'm doing this in a completely wrong way, I just thought that this method would be a good one.

Comment: The Collate directive in the DESCRIPTION file can help take care of which order to load files.

Comment: Alternative to using Collate you could just rename `class.r` to be alphabetically first. e.g., `00class.r`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking that renaming the files alphabetically is a bit none semantic. I was thinking about wrapping all of the class-extensions in functions, and just let the class-constructor-function do the loading in order.

Comment: @Rimbaud: if you're using roxygen2, then `#'@include class.r` ensures that `class.r` comes before that file in the collate order.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody, I made it work. @DirkEddelbuettel I have no idea what you wanted to archive with that comment.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Build the prerequisites:**
To build R Packages using RStudio, you should have the following prerequisites like
R,
RStudio,
Rtools,
Basic MikTex,
roxygen2 and devtools packages.

**2. Create the RPackage project in RStudio** and add all your R files (init.r,auth.r,class.r,modules/status.r,modules/mgmt.r,modules/core.r,modules/mcf.r) under the R folder of the project.

**3. Add the documentation** by editing the package description file. Build the project and now your package is ready to use.

it won't take more than 15 minutes to build a simple package.
If you wish to have step by step explanation to create a simple package, please visit this blog.
https://veeramaninatarajanmca.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/how-to-create-a-simple-package-in-r-using-rstudio/